# How to extract the normal vectors at the boundary nodes in gmsh?

Tags: mesh, boundary, fenics, gmsh

I have a geo file for gmsh and mesh it. Then I would like to extract the normal vectors at the nodes of a selected surface. How is this possible?

Below is my gmsh geo file.

```py
//Construct a cube in GMSH

//Build a line
Point(1) = {0, 0, 0, 1.0};
Point(2) = {0, 0, 10, 1.0};
Line(1) = {1, 2};

//Extrude line to create a surface (square)
Extrude {10, 0, 0} {
  Line{1};
}

//Extrude surface to create a volume (cube)
Extrude {0, 10, 0} {
  Surface{5};
}

//Six surfaces of the cube
Physical Surface(28) = {18};
Physical Surface(29) = {26};
Physical Surface(30) = {22}; 
Physical Surface(31) = {14};
Physical Surface(32) = {27};
Physical Surface(33) = {5};

//Volume of the cube
Physical Volume(34) = {1};
```

Comment: How do you define a normal at the node? In general, the nodes belong to several surfaces; thus, the direction of the normal has to be defined in some fashion. You can find the normal of a surface element (if it is curved – at a point belonging to the surface element).

Comment: Hi Anton, thanks for your message! As you say, for example, I would like to have a normal to the Physical Surface(28) = {18} at a given position (x,y,z) that lies within that surface. How can this be found within gmsh?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I don't know how to do it via a GEO file scripting (though, I would not be surprised if it exists).

However, it certainly can be done via GMSH API using [`getNormal()`](http://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#index-getNormal) function.

> `getNormal()`
>
> Get the normal to the surface with tag `tag` at the parametric coordinates `parametricCoord`. `parametricCoord` are given by pairs of *u* and *v* coordinates, concatenated: `[p1u, p1v, p2u, ...]`. `normals` are returned as triplets of *x*, *y*, *z* components, concatenated: `[n1x, n1y, n1z, n2x, ...]`.
>
> Input:
>   `tag`, `parametricCoord`
>
> Output: `normals`

GMSH API is available via Python, C/C++, and Julia. For details on the usage, I would suggest looking directly into how [API is defined in GMSH repository](https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/tree/master/api).